# Dijit.form.FilteringSelect initial display value

Tags: javascript, dojo

Is it possible to show and initial text in in a dijit.form.FilteringSelect wich is not an value. For example the search box on http://docs.dojocampus.org displayes the value "search" when it is not being used.

I have tried using `select.attr( "displayedValue", "My initial text" )` but becuase it is not an actual value the box will be marked as if it contains an invalid selection.

Answer (score 0):

I see an open enhancement for your question :: http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/3286